# Slide or roll up images using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, image-gallery

I have two JS buttons to rolling up and down as shown in
[this sample page](http://www.fedne.com/qstest.htm).

Now it's just change the image without effect, I need to apply the slide or the roll effect to make images looks circulating, something like [THIS](http://www.jscodes.com/codes/code21/) but up and down,

the JS code is dynamically generated from ASP.net Page,
here is the JS for up button,

```
var my_slots = ['_', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1',
                '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];


$("#sslot_img0_u").live('click', function() {
    image = document.getElementById('sslot_img' + '0');
    image.setAttribute('src', do_up('0', image.getAttribute('alt')));
    $("#hstring").val(my_slots[2]);
    return false;
});

function do_up(key1, key2) {
    image = document.getElementById('sslot_img' + key1);
    if (Number(key2) == my_slots.length - 1) {
        image.setAttribute('alt', '0');
        $get('sslot_hf' + key1).value = my_slots[0];
        return "http://www.fedne.com/" + my_slots[0] + '.gif';
    } else {
        image.setAttribute('alt', (Number(key2) + 1));
        $get('sslot_hf' + key1).value = my_slots[Number(key2) + 1];
        return "http://www.fedne.com/" + my_slots[Number(key2) + 1] + '.gif';
    }
}
```

and is it possible to get this effect on the button not the div click event?

Comment: I would recommend that you use a single image for the number spinner instead of 10 separate images. This will simplify the animation a great deal.

Comment: Nice idea, but the problem as showing in the code is, it's dynamically generated and i am using the `my_slots` array to show what numbers are showing.

Comment: With separate images, you'll have to: create the next number when they click either arrow, animate the current number and the next number appropriately, then destroy the first number. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that's my question, how to animate the current number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is achieved using the jquery animate() function, and tweaking the position attribute of elements. What you are using however is changing the existing value/image. The approach is different.

You might want to Right Click -> Inspect Element on the desired result in Chrome to get a clearer picture.

I hope I got your question right. Apologies if I didn't.

EDIT - Look into jquery slide() function documentation as well. May be what you need is there.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, Why can't apply animate() function, and tweaking in the button click event? i looked into jquery slide(), but it looks like hiding the current while sliding the next!

Comment: See right now, you are just getting the the next image and replacing the previous one, so you will not get the effect you want. Ideally, make one big graphic with all characters, put it in a div with fixed dimensions so that only one character is visible at a time, and then use slide() every time you press up and down key to move the element by a fixed amount (equivalent to character size).

Comment: Nice idea, but the problem as showing in the code is, it's dynamically generated and i am using the `my_slots` array to show what numbers are showing.

Comment: You can always edit the generated code. It serves as a guide, not as the final answer. I don't know how this code was generated in the first place, so I can't tell you how to adjust it to create the effect. I can just tell you how to do it from scratch. :)

Comment: so is the sample [here jscodes](http://www.jscodes.com/codes/code21/) , will get all the gallery images on the page load event then slide it?

Comment: Yes pretty much. It's like a frame on top of a joined graphic. The joint graphic keeps getting pulled through, and the frame allows only one to be seen at a time.